# Making a virtual shelf and populating it via a database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm trying to make a virtual shelf type of thing which is populated via a MySQL database. The column `shelfPos` holds the position of the item on the shelf. Each row/'shelf' starts with `<div class="shelfRow">` and obviously ends with `</div>` so it's styled and positioned correctly. Items on the shelves can be moved around using the jQuery UI droppable interaction.

The overall layout is this: http://jsfiddle.net/aRA5D/
Each shelf can hold 5 items (left to right).

I'm having trouble populating the shelves. At the moment I've got this: (This is in the place of the HTML)

```
<?php
$sql="SELECT * FROM shelf WHERE userID='$userID'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    // Show a message of some sort? (No items)
}
else {
    $tries = 1;
    $times = 10; // How many shelves. (10 = 2 shelves)

    while(($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) && ($tries <= $times)) {
        while ($tries <= $times) {
            if ($tries == $row['shelfPos']) {
                echo '<div class="drop" id="drop'.$tries.'"><div class="boxArt" id="'.$row['gameID'].'">'.$row['gameID'].'</div></div>';
            }
            else {
                echo '<div class="drop" id="drop'.$tries.'"></div>';
            }

            $tries = $tries + 1;
        }

        $times = $times + 5;
    }
}
?>
```

There's several things wrong with it. It doesn't include the `<div class="shelfRow">` html (didn't know how/where to put it, as it needs to be echoed after every 5 'blank' and real items - `for` loop maybe?) and it requires me to input the number of shelves (2 in this case). Would it be possible to determine how many shelves are required based on the item's position? It's awkward to do because it also needs to echo 'blank' `.drop` divs before and after them so that the items can be moved around.

Hope this all makes sense. Thanks for the help!

Comment: so i understand that u have problem with populating shelves in order?

Comment: Well, in the database 'shelfPos' holds the position of the items. I just need to correctly echo it so it appears at the correct position while echoing the other blank divs so that it can be moved. The code above seems to do this okay, but it requires me to enter the number of shelves and it doesn't echo the `<div class="shelfRow">` html for every 5 items. That's what I'm stuck on. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First u need to get data in order of ShelfPos

```
"SELECT * FROM shelf WHERE userID='$userID' order by shelfPos asc"
```

And try this code:

```
...
$i = 0;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

      //Each 5
      if($i % 5 == 0) echo '<div class="shelfRow">';

        if ($i == $row['shelfPos']) {
            echo '<div class="drop" id="drop'.$i.'"><div class="boxArt" id="'.$row['gameID'].'">'.$row['gameID'].'</div></div>';
        }
        else {
            echo '<div class="drop" id="drop'.$i.'"></div>';
        }

        //close shelfrow div
        if($i % 5 == 4) echo '</div>';

        $i++;
    }

 //to complete the loop
 $shelv_left = 5 - ($i % 5);
 if($shelv_left < 5) {
 for($j=0; $j < $shelv_left; $j++) {
    echo '<div class="drop" id="drop'.($i+$j).'"></div>';
 }
 echo '</div>'; // end shelfrow div
}
...
```

Comment: Ah, that's great. Thanks! Would there be a way to make it loop multiple times though, as it only loops depending on how many rows there are atm. Say if $row['shelfPos'] = 4, it would need to loop 5 times so there are 3 blank divs, the item div, then another blank one. Thanks again! :)

Comment: i have changed code above, please check and if it works accept the answer please

Comment: Thanks! Works great. I'll just have to study it now to see how it works. :P